# Why am I getting a "not a cmdlet" error from inside a here-string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, powershell

Below is an extract of my html code, defined as $html in my Powershell script:

```
$html = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful/1.0.2/css/jquery.circliful.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful/1.0.2/js/jquery.circliful.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"></style>

    <title>Orders</title>

    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 2%; font-size: 300%">Actual Vs Expected orders for Today:</h3>
                <h2 style="text-align: center; color: #ff3333; margin-top: 2.5%; font-size: 500%">$SAPTodayExel<small style="color: #000000">/$ExpectedExelOrders</small></h2>                              
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div id="test-circle"></div>
                    <table style="margin-top: 100px; width:75%; position: fixed; bottom: 40px;">

 <tr>
    <th style="font-size: 16px; width:11%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 49%,#a1dbff 100%)">12</th>
    <td style="font-size: 30px; color: #ff3333; width:20%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 49%,#a1dbff 100%)">$SAPTodayNonConExel</td>
    <th style="font-size: 16px; width:8%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 49%,#a1dbff 100%)">13</th>
    <td style="font-size: 30px; color: #ff3333; width:20%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 49%,#a1dbff 100%)">$SAPTodayPOSExel</td>
    <th style="font-size: 16px; width:8%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 49%,#a1dbff 100%)">24</th>
    <td style="font-size: 30px; color: #ff3333; width:15%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 49%,#a1dbff 100%)">$SAPTodayROIExel</td>
    <th style="font-size: 16px; width:7%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 49%,#a1dbff 100%)">245</th>
    <td style="font-size: 30px; color: #ff3333; width:20%; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f9ff 0%,#cbebff 49%,#a1dbff 100%)">$SAPTodayUnited</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
                </div>
            </div>
    </head>

<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload=function(){
        $( document ).ready(function() { // 6,32 5,38 2,34
            $("#test-circle").circliful({
            foregroundColor: "#cb60b3",
            backgroundColor: "#e5e7e9",
            pointColor: "none",
            fillColor: 'none',
            foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
            backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
            pointSize: 28.5,
            fontColor: '#aaa',

            animation: 1,
            animationStep: 5,

            showPercent: 1,
            noPercentageSign: false,
            replacePercentageByText: null,
            percentageTextSize: 22,         
            percent: $PercentReceived,
            multiPercentage: 0,
            percentages: null,

            targetPercent: null,
            targetTextSize: 12,
            targetColor: '#2980B9',

            icon: 'none',
            iconSize: '30',
            iconColor: '#ccc',
            iconPosition: 'top',

            target: 0,
            start: 0,

            textBelow: true,            
            text: null,
            textStyle: "font-size: 10px",
            textColor: '#17202a',
            textAdditionalCss: 'test',

            halfCircle: false,
            animateInView: false,
            decimals: 0,
            alwaysDecimals: false
            });
        });
    }
        </script>
</html>
"@

$html | out-file "c:\test.html"
```

When I run this as an html file, it runs perfectly normal and the script is running as expected. However, if I parse this via PS it comes up with an error:

> document : The term 'document' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet,  function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or  if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:46 char:6
>   +         $( document ).ready(function() { // 6,32 5,38 2,34
>   +            ~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (document:String) [], CommandNot     FoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I have tried changing "$( document )" to "$("document"), adding in quotations, which seems to work, but when you look at the html file on output, it removes the "$(" and ")", so it effectively disables the script from enabling due to incorrect syntax.

Is it because it is seeing the dollar sign as a PS variable? How do I go around this?

Thanks

Comment: From the syntax highlighting, it seems that you have not escaped your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem line, as you know, has this

> ```
> $( document )
> ```

That is syntax for PowerShell [subexpressions $()](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). PowerShell is telling you that "document" is not a command. Use backticks to escape that "$" in PowerShell so it wont treat it special

```
`$( document )
```

You have a similar issue with the following line that might not be as obvious

> ```
> $("#test-circle").circliful({
> ```

looks like this in your here string once processed

```
#test-circle.circliful({
```

You need to escape that dollar sign as well.

---

You could have just used a herestring with single quotes (`@' '@`) and that would have avoided this issue. However since you are variable substitution you cannot go that route without more changes.